# How to disable the error log file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

here I try to disable the error log and debug log files, even when the core is enabled.

I tried the following code.

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
  'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
  'level' => 0,
  'trace' => false
));
```

but it only disables debug log.

is there any other way to disable error log and debug log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

another parameter as 'log' and set it to true

Or you can use constant LOG_DEBUG in your core.php and set it to true.

The details of which are given here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html

Comment: its not working, the link you attached also not available

Comment: Are you sure the link is not working...as its looking good at my end?

Comment: no its not working for me. it shows "The book.cakephp.org page isn’t working, book.cakephp.org didn’t send any data."